# What is causing parsing error in my /etc/fstab

Tags: scripts, error-handling, etc

I am trying to mount Google Drive, but I am getting the following error:

> mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 12 -- ignored
>   mount: /home/kao/Google Drive: can't find in /etc/fstab.

The line is the following:

```
gdfuse#default  /home/kao/Google\ Drive     fuse    uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,user,_netdev     0       0
```

Comment: Where did you get this line? What do you mean by `gdfuse#default`?

Comment: [fstab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/fstab.5.html): If the name of the mount point contains spaces or tabs these can be escaped as `\040' and '\011' respectively.

Comment: Pilot6, I got it from a automount guide here:

https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Automounting

It's needed to make google drive mount on a startup. 

Bac0n, as you can see I have used backward slash in Google\ Drive in order to escape space

Comment: literally... /home/kao/Google\040Drive

Comment: Alright, It helped, but now I am getting this:

Error: Mountpoint Drive should be an existing directory.

Even though there is a directory called Google Drive in /home/kao

Comment: any help on that?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same error - here is my fix:

Using \0x40 in fstab is correct for addressing the space in the mount point name in /etc/fstab, however, when it is passed as an argument to the 'gfuser' script it is changed back into a space which results in the script treating it as 2 arguments.  I modified my 'gfuser' script by changing

> `su $USERNAME -l -c "google-drive-ocamlfuse -label $1 $*"`

to

> `su $USERNAME -l -c "google-drive-ocamlfuse -label $1 '$2'"`

by 'single quoting' the second argument from fstab (which is the mount point) the command google-drive-ocamlfuse picks up on the space...

Good luck!